# Android AVD wifi error

Tags: android, eclipse

In the Android AVD I can surf the internet through the browser, but I can't turn the wifi on, and I also set using wireless network and GPS satellites.

Anybody know?

AND:

I have downloaded the GPX file and loaded it,but it does work at all,should i download a local GPX file (China ),Unfortunately,I can not find where to donload it.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use WiFi Connection or GPS in Emulator. Emulator is just a software for testing purpose. When you are opening any site in the emulator, by default it uses your computer's internet connection, this is the reason you are able to open any site in the emulator.

However you can simulate GPS in Emulator by inserting .GPX file which contains lat-lon details. you can see an [example](http://www.backcountrynavigator.com/content/gpx-file-android-gps-app-tracks-and-waypoints) of gpx file, how it works.

You can find the gpx in DDMS window, like below image,

> [image]

Comment: I have downloaded the GPX file and loaded it,but it does work at all,should i download a local GPX file (China ),Unfortunately,I can not find where to donload it.

Comment: GPX contains sample lat-lon, which can be of any place of world. for real experience , i suggest you to test in device.

Answer (score 0):

AVD Does not contain Wifi Hardware.
If you want to emulate GPS then use android Emulator