# Set latitude and longitude value to text box

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android AVD wifi error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834164/android-avd-wifi-error)

I am working with Android, and I want to show current latitude value in textbox and current longitude value in another textbox. And I wrote the below code, but it is not working. It is not setting any latitude or longitude value in the corresponding textbox. Is there any problem with my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    private static final String TAG = "CurrentLocation";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat1);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat2);

     // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       if (location != null) {
           System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
           int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
           int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
           Log.e("GPS", "location changed: lat="+lat+", lon="+lng);
           latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
           longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
       } else {
           latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
           longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Or I need to do something such as passing latitude or longitude value from somwhere? Or it will automatically get the current location value?

I have these in my manifest file-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Anything else I need to add?

And also I am getting this error when I saw in logCAT

```
07-18 22:43:59.836: E/Trace(3410): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I am getting in my textbox as `Provider Not Available` as it is going to else loop.

Comment: Are you getting logs which u printed in onLocationchange.

Comment: No I am not getting the logs.

Comment: So your onLocation change is not getting called. set required permission in Manifest.

Comment: I updated my question with permission I am using in manifest xml file.

Comment: @rjchar, have you given location permission in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the permission I am using in manifest xml file.

Comment: Give some time for location update, first time it takes much time to load.

Comment: I am confuse in a way, Suppose If I am runnign the above code, then automatically I will be getting latitude and longitude values, right? There is nothing I need to set or pass the values from somewhere?

Comment: And I am getting in the textbox now Provider not available as it is going to else loop.

Comment: wait a min, are you testing it in a room ?

Comment: ummm, Yes I am running this in my eclipse and currently sitting in my room. Anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Yes... you need to check it in real device, under open field(sky) or near window

Comment: Ok. But there should be some way to check this out in eclipse also? right? I remember there was some way where we can check this out using DDMS I guess. I cannot remember currently.

Comment: Yup, now I got it. in DDMS you can do that, Yes its working for me now after passing values manually using DDMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554556/set-latitude-and-longitude-value-to-text-box#comment15281574_11554556) that you are running your code from eclipse. Let me tell you that, can not fetch the real GPS Co-Ordinates in Eclipse. However you can simulate it by load .gpx file in to DDMS.

Have a visit my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834224/996493) for same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
           int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
```

you should have double instead of int, Do you know lat, longs are in double and you are only taking integer part. location changes even after 4 decimal places.

Comment: but that's a perfect int type casting.

Comment: Yes i know its perfect, But Should one not mention logical errors in code,int for lat,long  is worst, Am i Wrong!!

Comment: you are right in your way, but the type casting is not wrong, that's what i am saying :), anyways i found the solution, OP is testing in eclipse, that's what the problem is.

Comment: u mean in emulator!! , OMG, lolz.